# sessionStorage not functioning (on shopify?)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, shopify

I'm trying to use session storage to make a popup appear only once per browser session. The popup correctly appears and is deleted after 2 seconds as set by my timer, but it keeps re-appearing after reloading the page. I am sure the storage token does get recorded as I checked in the console, so I don't know where the error comes from. I am using shopify, is it possible that shopify empties session storage every refresh and how could I counter that?

Here is my code:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('AnnouncementOnce') !== 'true') {
    function popupwin(){
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }
sessionStorage.setItem('AnnouncementOnce','true');
}

var delay = ( function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

delay(function(){
    const element = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    element.remove();
}, 2000 );
```

Thanks in advance!